# TypeError in Orders#delivery(time + time?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In code:

```
<%= Time.now%> # 2014-12-06 11:38:55 +0530
<%= @hotel.deliverytime%> # 2000-01-01 00:30:00 UTC
```

Below operation causing the error :-

```
<% @delivery_time=Time.now + @hotel.deliverytime%>
```

I want to add both time. This error is due to different time format. So, how do i add these fields.Please help me out.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your code using the method [`#to_i`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Time.html#method-i-to_i).

```
<% @delivery_time = Time.now + @hotel.deliverytime.to_i %>
```

As `@hotel.deliverytime` is giving you the `UTC` timestamp, convert it to the *equivalent* seconds first, and then add it with the `Time` object. This is how you need to do, as [`Time#+`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Time.html#method-i-2B) accepts its arguments as *some number of seconds (possibly fractional)*.

Comment: Still getting the same error, after using `<%= @delivery_time = Time.now.utc + @hotel.deliverytime %>`

Comment: Thanks @Arup it's so easy.